# Save gzip compressed data to cache storage from service worker

Tags: service-worker

We are trying to store some api responses in cache storage for a PWA app.We are intercepting the fetch request in service worker and are storing the responses to cache.But our uncompressed apis size is little large and we want to keep the compressed(gzip) version in the cache and uncompress it when needed.
Is there any way we can prevent the browser from automatically uncompressing the responses from server

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this automatically. Most servers will only compress their response bodies on the fly if the incoming request indicates that the browser supports compression, and in that case, the browser will automatically decompress the body before you have access to the compressed bytes.

You may have better luck either explicitly compressing the files on the server and downloading and storing that compressed version (i.e. `fetch('asset.json.gz')`), or alternatively, using a [`CompressionStream`](https://web.dev/streams/#useful-streams-available-in-the-browser) (which isn't widely supported outside of Chromium-based browsers) to compress your data client-side prior to storing it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.Indeed we are going for the manual compression and decompression from server and client side.